# LA->Tokyo->Seoul and back. Do I need a visa?

Tags: international-travel

Travelling LAX>TYO>LAX roundtrip.  Planning on doing a side roundtrip TYO>SEL>TYO. do I have to purchase roundtrip TYO>SEL>TYO tickets prior to entering Japan, or can I buy the roundtrip  TYO>SEL>TYO tickets when I arrive in Japan?

Comment: What country issued your Passport?

Comment: Without knowing your citizenship, and country of residence if different, it's not possible to determine if you need a visa to visit South Korea.

Comment: You need to state your citizenship and country of residence, because those are deciding factors in whether you need a visa for Japan and Korea.  It's like asking which phone cable to buy without saying which phone you have.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy the TYO>SEL>TYO at a later date. You should be covered by your LAX>TYO>LAX. Just make sure your via covers all the time for the LAX>TYO>LAX trip.

Comment: And if OP actually needs a visa for Japan, that the visa is dual or multiple entries, of course.